# ASP.NET Core Dependecy Injection in Extension Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I would like to extend `UserManager` to allow finding user by UserName. I have created a extension method. I have noticed the easiest way to achieve it is to get `UserStore`. I cannot do this by `UserManager` because `Store` is protected. I decided to use DI to inject `UserStore` into my method but I am not even sure it is possible.

I have tried to pass as a second argument `IUserStore<T> store` but VS says no argument has been given.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Learning.Extensions
{
    public static class UserManagerExtension
    {
        public static Task<T> FindByUserNameAsync<T>(this UserManager<T> userManager, IUserStore<T> store, string userName) where T : class
        {
            var result = store.FindByNameAsync(userName, CancellationToken.None);

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot inject into a static method.

Comment: And what class/version are you using anyway?  I think UserManager already has FindByName and FindByLogin  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the existing method to search for a user by name:

```
public Task<TUser> UserManager<TUser>.FindByNameAsync(String);
```

More information can be found in [ASP.NET Core Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.findbynameasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_UserManager_1_FindByNameAsync_System_String_).